# class properties

Tags: c#, class, function

I've just began using classes and would like to make some functions of a class visible outside that class. The problem is that I haven't got (and unable to have) a variable of type Abc.
Let me explain with a snippet of code:

```
class Abc
{
    private float foo;
    public float Foo {
        get { return foo; }
        set { foo = value; }
    }

    public static void Hello() {
        foo = 5.0f;
        Console.WriteLine("Hello everyone!");
    }
}

.... somewhere else ....

Abc bar;
bar.Foo = 5.0f;       // ok, I know this
bar.Hello();          // fine, I know this too

Abc.Hello();          // I'm trying to do this!
```

**EDIT:**
Ok, now suppose I would like to assign something to `foo` in Hello (as in my code). I know this might sound like a nonsense, so I'm not sure it's even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `static` member function.  `static` member functions are not associated with a particular *instance* of the class, which is what you will need if you want to access them via the *class itself*.  The specifics vary slightly depending on whether you're interested in C++ or C#.

Comment: So can't I use foo in Hello()?

Comment: @BlackBear: No, because `foo` is non-static; i.e. each instance of `Abc` has its own copy.  If you did `Abc.Hello()`, which copy of `foo` would you want it to access?

Answer (score 0):

Make `Hello()` static; that way it does not require an instantiation of the class.

`public static void Hello() { ...`